# Vibrate iPhone when click a collection view cell not working Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I have a app which has simple UICollectionView

I am just need when did select any cell from this collectionView app make a vibration

here's my Code

```
import AudioToolbox

ManualWaveCollectionView : UICollectionViewDataSource  , UICollectionViewDelegate , UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout{
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = self.collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "locationsCell", for: indexPath) as! LocationCollectionViewCell
        let location = self.cellLocations[indexPath.row]
        cell.locationName.text = location.location
        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.cellLocations.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(SystemSoundID(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate))
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(SystemSoundID(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate))   
    }
}
```

there are nothing happen it's just keep print **()** when click in the collectionViewCell

iam using Iphone 5s

Comment: Documentation states, that `kSystemSoundID_Vibrate` should be use together with `AudioServicesPlayAlertSound` not `AudioServicesPlaySystemSound`. Also read the documentation, since the audio sesion has to be configured properly.

Answer (score 1):

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(SystemSoundID(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate))  
}
```